# Bridge between Java and C#

Tags: c#, java, platform-independent, language-interoperability

I have been given a task to create a bridge between C# and Java. It was said that if we use C# right now, and then we receive a Java file from somewhere else, we should be able to convert that Java file into .NET so it can be compatible with our software. The problem is I don't know what to do or how to even begin this task. Any suggestions or advice?

It was said that I initially have to make platform independent classes, if that helps.

*Edit: Sorry if I wasn't clear the first time, because I don't fully understand the task myself, which is why I am here. But from what I understand, I do have to create the bridge itself where I can call the source Java code from my .NET file. I have several months to finish it, so I assume that I have to make every library in Java compatible with C#.

I looked around for help, and found some similar projects: JNBridge(pay to use), Tangible(free demo), and Janett(open source), so that is what I am basing my opinion from.

**Edit: Let's say for example I create a Calculator class in Java. I would want to create the instance of that class in C#.

Comment: what do you mean by Java file? Java source code (or) data sent by system which was developed in Java (or) some other language?

Comment: Are you wanting to (1) communicate with existing Java-compiled code from C# (like a "bridge"), or (2) port Java code to C# ("convert that Java file into .NET")?  Your question isn't at all clear in this respect.  And these are completely different things/tasks.

Comment: this is a pretty daunting task...assuming you mean source code, is this even feasible? c# and java have pretty strong similarities but certain constructs dont even exist in java that do in c# and vise versa. for example linq, delegates, dynamic types, anonymous objects, etc..

Comment: You can convert Java binaries to .NET See http://www.ikvm.net/

Comment: You can try the [JLCA](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14349) although i've never used it and doubt that it'll work in any later than VS 2005. Here are more infos: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163422.aspx

Comment: @TimSchmelter, JLCA is for VS2003 and no newer version is available.

Comment: @L.B: But according to my second link above: "the JLCA is included with Visual Studio 2005 "

Comment: @TimSchmelter OK, I was wrong, It is 2 years younger. But that's all. I used it and wouldn't recommend for anyone.

Comment: Question as stated is ridiculously. You receive a java file from where? What kind of file, a .java that needs to be converted to a .cs file (hard to do good), a .jar file that needs to be decompiled and recompiled as a .NET binary (did I mentioned impossible?)? And do you want it to be executed afterwards? And why do you want to do all of this?I  really can't believe the upvoter.

Comment: @CodeCaster, Please try IKVM. I used it to convert Lucene, Jericho Html Parser, Mobile Atlas Creator etc binaries to .Net and used in many projects. It is not a joke, it is real. I really can't believe this ignorance.

Comment: @CodeCaster, you can even host java classes (without prior conversion) in .Net :) I really want to see who voted for close.

Comment: @L.B the techniques can exist, which I do not question, but the question itself is too vague.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have never used this, [IKVM.NET](http://www.ikvm.net/) may be worth checking out.

> IKVM.NET is an implementation of Java for Mono and the Microsoft .NET
>   Framework. It includes the following components:
>
> ```
> - A Java Virtual Machine implemented in .NET
> - A .NET implementation of the Java class libraries
> - Tools that enable Java and .NET interoperability
> ```

The one time I've seen it was a while ago, when working with a proprietary .NET based CMS. That assembly was used, but I'm not sure in what capacity.

Comment: I don't know how I missed IKVM, but I think I need to make something which resembles it, because it convert Java libraries to .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the situation, there are a large number of integration technologies that can be used to bridge two systems. In fact, there is an entire software architecture *paradigm* devoted to this called a Service Oriented Architecture. Any of the techniques used for inter-service communication can be used to integrate *any* two systems, no matter the size. There are tradeoffs, of course, but there always are.

Without *much* more information regarding the systems involved and the level of integration needed, it is going to be *very* hard for a definitive answer to be found for this question.

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation of what you want your bridge to do, it sounds like JNBridge could well solve your problem and save a lot of time reinventing the wheel.  If you have any questions, please contact us at JNBridge -- there's a contact link on the website.  (Disclosure: Yes, I work for JNBridge.)